# Loop that calculates specific values and writes it in a text file

Tags: python, loops

I was needing help with a simple code that will use a loop to calculate stoichiometry and density. with these values I wanted to put them in a text file. Below is the code.

```
  den_U = 19.1 #density of uranium 238 g/cc
  den_C = 2.26 #density of carbon 12 g/cc

  molm_U = 238.02 #molar mass of Uranium g/mol
  molm_C = 12.0107 #molar mass of Carbon g/mol

  a = 1

  for i in range(20): 
      input = 'density_and_stoich4'
      file = open(input + '.txt', 'w')
      T_C = molm_C*a
      T_com = T_C + molm_U 
      per_C = T_C/T_com
      per_U = molm_U/T_com
      den_com = den_U*per_U + den_C*per_C
      d = a

      file.writelines(str(den_com)+ ';')
      file.writelines(str(d) + '.0\n')
      file.close()

  a += 10
```

the problem with the code is it only executes once. I would like it to execute multiple times and write in the text file like below.

```
  18.2334;1.0
  17.3437;11.0
  16.3422;21.0
```

and so on.

Comment: So what's stopping you?  Wrap a loop around the things you want to repeat.  `a += 10` is the bottom of that loop.

Comment: Move the `file = open(...)` and `file.close()` calls outside the loop. As it is written now, you're overwriting the file every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'w'` in `open()` means write mode, which will overwrite the file content. You need to:

1. Open the file before loop
2. write the content inside the loop
3. close the file after the loop

It is better to use a `with` statement so the file gets auto closed after the block. And avoid using `file` as a variable name because it is a reserved keyword. For example:

```
with open(input + '.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(den_com) + ';' + str(d) + '.0\n')
```

Note: `writelines()` is used if you want to write multiple lines which isn't true in your case. You should use `write()` instead